# When creating flow of "when file created" seek subfolders

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I'm trying to set up a workflow as shown in this picture. [image: File created flow]

> So my Flow is: When a file is created in Shared Folders/Parent, send
>   an email.

- **Shared Folders/Parent/file.ext** kicks off the Flow
- **Shared Folders/Parent/Child/file.ext** does not kick off the Flow

This all works fine and as I expected I suppose. However, I can not specify that when a file is created in a parent folder, to look inside its subfolders. Is this possible? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I may have overlooked this option. Not to look at a certain Folder but check the entire library. From there, I can probably get more specific using some params and functions to the the folder hierarchy[image: solution].